# How to secure access to SPA on Google App Engine

Tags: security, google-app-engine

I have an SinglePageApplication written in HTML5, Javascript and jQuery. It currently has no backend processing associated with it at all - everything is client side. I host it on the Google App Engine free tier.

I want to add some security to this, so that only known users are able to access the application. Is there a standard Google way of doing this? Or any other standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is likely to depend on how you want to authenticate the users. A couple of options:

1. Set up the [Cloud Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/) in front of your app, which is really quick and easy. You'd need each person to have a Google account that you'd add to the [proxy settings in the console](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/iap).

   Users would get prompted for which Google account to use to
   authorize access:

   [image: Sign in]

   If the user isn't in the allowed list, they would see something like:

   [image: Not allowed user]

   2. If you trust your users, you could add them to your GCP console project with `viewer` permissions and then use the `login: admin` handler in your `app.yaml` handler. These users wouldn't be able to modify your project, but they would be able to view resources within it, so be careful.
   3. Build identity into your app directly with [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), which is handled on the client side if you don't need long lived access/refresh tokens. It has the bonus of supporting a number of identity providers (Facebook, Twitter, etc), but does involve more work. Might consider it depending on where you expect your application to go in the future.
   4. Use other open source tools to implement an identity/auth system.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer - not only does it give me a number of options, it also gives me a migration path from alpha release to beta :)

Comment: 4. Use various available open source tools to implement oauth2 login. Here is one example: https://github.com/authomatic/authomatic